Why does moviepy insist on specifying fps, but ignore its value
I'm stitching individual images together to make a movie with moviepy using the following code:
from moviepy.editor import *

# List image filenames
images = [f for f in img_dict[key_list[0]]]

# Define clip duration (assuming all images have same duration)
clip_duration = 1/24  # Adjust clip duration per image (in seconds)

# Create video clips from images
clips = [ImageClip('/'.join((IMG_DIR / Path(image)).parts)).set_duration(clip_duration) for image in images]
#clips = [ImageClip('/'.join((IMG_DIR / Path(image)).parts)).set_duration(clip_duration) for image in images]
print(len(clips))


concat_clip = concatenate_videoclips(clips, method="compose")
concat_clip.fps = 24
concat_clip.write_videofile("test5.mp4")

If I don't set_duration, I get an error. If I don't set fps before executing write_videofile (or set fps as a named arg for write_videofile), I get an error. If the duration I set and fps are inconsistent, the created video is consistent with the duration I set and not fps.
If I need to use set_duration, why am I required to set fps, which seems to be ignored? (Note: In this code duration & fps are consistent, but I have also allowed them to be inconsistent and found fps was ignored)
